# Progress Bar is not displaying on screen while using asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

> I am facing an issue. I am using **Json** to **fetch data** from **my server**. So basically my app perform some data fetching and showing on layout. I'm using **AsyncTask**. It's working like charm but problem is that it's not showing my progress bar while fetching data on the screen.

**Here is my AsyncTask's Methods.**

```
 class LoadAlbumsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<TeamAlbum>>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(Team.this);
        pd.setMessage("Fetching Data....");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        try {
            Glide.with(Team.this).load(R.drawable.te).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new TeamAdapter(Team.this, albumList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Team.this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    protected List<TeamAlbum> doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        try {
            Client client = new Client();
            Service service = client.getClient().create(Service.class);

            Call<TeamResponse> call = service.getAlbums();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<TeamResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<TeamResponse> call, Response<TeamResponse> response) {
                    List<TeamAlbum> iteams = response.body().getAlbums();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new TeamAdapter(getApplicationContext(), iteams));
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<TeamResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(Team.this, "Error Fetching Data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pd.dismiss();

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(Team.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return albumList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<TeamAlbum> list) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new TeamAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list));
        pd.dismiss();
    }

}


private  void loadJSON(){
    new LoadAlbumsAsync().execute();
}
```

Can someone help me out what is the problem with my code.why it is not displaying progress bar?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whenever you `enqueue()` something with a `Callback` object, it's a good bet that it's already an asynchronous operation. That is, you don't need the `AsyncTask` just to enqueue it. The code you have in `doInBackground()` is returning immediately, so `onPostExecute()` immediately follows, and your `ProgressDialog` gets dismissed nearly instantaneously.

Comment: I@MikeM. I used AsyncTask because Everytime It's freeze for while when I moved from Main Activity to Team Activity.

Comment: @MikeM. Even Right now I am facing issue of skipping frames but it's nearly around 49 to 60, before it was 270 to 400 frames.

Comment: @MikeM. Do you have any idea to completely removing skipping frames issue ?

Comment: Nope, because we have no idea what the rest of your setup is, but I doubt that the stuff you now have in `doInBackground()` was the main cause.